# Make DatePicker easier to read when disabled

Tags: wpf, xaml

The text is grayed out when the DatePicker is disabled and I want the content to be easier to read.

What I did on some TextBoxes was:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

It did make the text easier to read.

I do manage to change the Foreground colour on the DataPicker but it does not do the trick. The text was still grayed out.

Seems like there is another property I need to set to make the content of the disabled DatePicker easier to read.

So, how do I make the content of my disabled DatePicker easier to read?

Comment: i'm afraid you have to get to the template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you extend DatePicker by adding bool DependencyProperty called Editable.
I found a working example at the following [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/fi-FI/wpf/thread/0e4d6c8c-987c-489e-bb9c-6170a9cf5ed0), note that I run this code in .NET 4.

Here is the DatePicker Control:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace DatePickerStyle
{
 public class ExtendedDatePicker : DatePicker
 {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EditableProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Editable", typeof(bool),
        typeof(ExtendedDatePicker), new PropertyMetadata(true));
    public bool Editable
    {
       get { return (bool)GetValue(EditableProperty); }
       set { SetValue(EditableProperty, value); }
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
       base.OnApplyTemplate();
       var textBox = GetTemplateChild("PART_TextBox") as DatePickerTextBox;
       var binding = new Binding { Source = this, Path = new PropertyPath(ExtendedDatePicker.EditableProperty) };
       textBox.SetBinding(UIElement.FocusableProperty, binding);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DatePickerStyle.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:DatePickerStyle="clr-namespace:DatePickerStyle" 
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DatePicker IsEnabled="True" Grid.Row="0" SelectedDate="2002/12/31"/>
    <DatePicker IsEnabled="False" Grid.Row="1" SelectedDate="2002/12/31"/>
    <DatePickerStyle:ExtendedDatePicker Editable="True" Grid.Row="2" SelectedDate="2002/12/31"/>
    <DatePickerStyle:ExtendedDatePicker Editable="False" Grid.Row="3" SelectedDate="2002/12/31"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2):

My I suggest this simpler, universal approach?

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyDisabledDatePicker">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
        <TextBlock 
            Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, StringFormat={}{0:d}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="10,0,0,0"/>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"  Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource MyDisabledDatePicker}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Presto!

Comment: this can result in same real bad error. if you bindg your isenabled to a viewmodel and eg. in a save command you change your isenabled to false, and then back to true. you got an error as far as you click the datepicker popup.

Answer (score 1):

the above code w ExtendedDatePicker works, first I thought it didn't but that was because the dropdown could still change the text and the Editable="False" doesn't work on the dropdown

so don't forget to add the following to the ExtendedDatePicker

```
Editable="False" AllowDrop="False" IsDropDownOpen="False" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsManipulationEnabled="False"
```